# How to use options.query in android socket.io?

Tags: java, android, node.js, socket.io

```
IO.Options options = new IO.Options();

options.forceNew=true;

options.reconnection = false;

options.query = "loginId="+loginid;

Socket socket = IO.socket("https://myserver:8000/", options);
```

Then i check query is available in server. But haven't query error

Comment: What error? see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: var handshakeData = socket.request;

if(!socket.handshake.query)
   next(new Error('-Error code:1')); --> that error

Answer (score 8):

You can use

```
options.query = "loginId="+loginid+"&foo=bar"; // and so on..
```